# How should I make one column fix and others repeatable in sql procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

There is one scheme and different bidders against it, so the scenario is that if user send SchemeID to the procedure then it should return the SchemeName, EstimatedCost (*once*) and all bidders against single scheme i.e.  BidderName, BidPrice, SchemeEstimatedCost... in this format

```
 SchemeName EstimatedCost   BidderName   BidPrice 
  Scheme 1      13000          John        12000        
                               Aamir       10000 
                               Shumail      9000
                               Michael      8090
```

See I am searching data via SchemeID, it should return me detail in this format.

My try:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectBidsByBidID]

    @fk_Schemes_Bids_SchemeID int

AS
BEGIN

         Select Schemes.SchemeName, Schemes.SchemeCost as SchemeEstimatedCost, 
                Bids.BidBidderName, Bids.BidPrice
         From Bids
         Inner Join Schemes
         ON Schemes.pk_Schemes_SchemeID= Bids.fk_Schemes_Bids_SchemeID
         Where Bids.fk_Schemes_Bids_SchemeID= 3

END
```

but it repeats the SchemeName and Estimated cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectBidsByBidID]

@fk_Schemes_Bids_SchemeID int

AS
BEGIN

     Select case when ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by BidPrice desc) = 1  then Schemes.SchemeName else '' end as SchemeName, case when ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by BidPrice desc) = 1 then Schemes.SchemeCost else '' end as  SchemeEstimatedCost, 
            Bids.BidBidderName, Bids.BidPrice
     From Bids
     Inner Join Schemes
     ON Schemes.pk_Schemes_SchemeID= Bids.fk_Schemes_Bids_SchemeID
     Where Bids.fk_Schemes_Bids_SchemeID= 3
Order by BidPrice desc
END
```

However, as stated previously, this should not be done in the query, but in the report viewer/generator.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SelectBidsBySchemeID, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SelectBidsBySchemeID, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SelectBidsBySchemeID, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Possible in RDLC report ?

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectBidsByBidID]

    @fk_Schemes_Bids_SchemeID int

AS
BEGIN
;with cte
as
(
         Select Schemes.SchemeName, Schemes.SchemeCost as SchemeEstimatedCost, 
                Bids.BidBidderName, Bids.BidPrice,row_number() over(partition by schemename,SchemeCost order by bidprice desc) as rn
         From Bids
         Inner Join Schemes
         ON Schemes.pk_Schemes_SchemeID= Bids.fk_Schemes_Bids_SchemeID
         Where Bids.fk_Schemes_Bids_SchemeID= 3
)
select case when rn=1 then Schemes.SchemeName else '' end as SchemeName, case when rn=1 then cast(Schemes.SchemeCost as varchar(max)) else '' end as SchemeEstimatedCost, 
                Bids.BidBidderName, Bids.BidPrice
from cte

END
```

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SelectBidsBySchemeID, Line 18
The multi-part identifier "Schemes.SchemeName" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SelectBidsBySchemeID, Line 18
The multi-part identifier "Schemes.SchemeCost" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SelectBidsBySchemeID, Line 19
The multi-part identifier "Bids.BidBidderName" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SelectBidsBySchemeID, Line 19
The multi-part identifier "Bids.BidPrice" could not be bound.

Answer (score 1):

This should be done in a reporting tool/ any other front end tool. If you have no option try this

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectBidsByBidID] @fk_Schemes_Bids_SchemeID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN sno = 1
                THEN SchemeName
            ELSE ''
            END AS SchemeName
        ,CASE 
            WHEN sno = 1
                THEN SchemeEstimatedCost
            ELSE ''
            END AS SchemeEstimatedCost
        ,BidBidderName
        ,BidPrice
    FROM (
        SELECT row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY Schemes.SchemeName
                ,Schemes.SchemeCost ORDER BY Bids.BidPrice DESC
                ) AS sno
            ,Schemes.SchemeName
            ,Schemes.SchemeCost AS SchemeEstimatedCost
            ,Bids.BidBidderName
            ,Bids.BidPrice
        FROM Bids
        INNER JOIN Schemes ON Schemes.pk_Schemes_SchemeID = Bids.fk_Schemes_Bids_SchemeID
        WHERE Bids.fk_Schemes_Bids_SchemeID = 3
        ) AS t
END
```

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SelectBidsBySchemeID, Line 18
The multi-part identifier "Bids.BidBidderName" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SelectBidsBySchemeID, Line 19
The multi-part identifier "Bids.BidPrice" could not be bound.